# Chrome driver not working with proxy

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use Chrome Driver with proxy first time but it does not seem to work. Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
    proxy = '1.1.1.1'
    proxy_url = 'https://usr:pwd@' + proxy.strip().rstrip('\n')
    print(proxy_url)
service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(CHROME_PATH)
service.start()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy_url)
options = options.to_capabilities()
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, options)
driver.set_window_size(1400, 1000)
driver.get("http://google.com")
print(driver.page_source)
```

No matter what site I use it returns:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Sorry I can't share original proxy as they don't belong to me. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have you checked manually set this proxy in chrome?

Comment: @Sraw.. No.. but the proxy is working. What else are you trying to tell?